# CameraX: Output of ImageAnalysis looks corrupted/scattered

Tags: android, zxing, android-camerax

I'm working on an QR scanning application that is based on CameraX. The scanning works as expected on most devices except a few random devices. After debugging this issue for a long time, I found out that the cropped image is kind of shattered on the device in which scanning wasn't working.

**Expected output (works on Pixel Device):**

[image]

**Current output (on the devices in which scanning is not working):**

[image]

The **analyze** method that receives each frame (part of the CustomImageAnalyzer class)

```
    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        val byteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer

        if (imageData.size != byteBuffer.capacity()) {
            imageData = ByteArray(byteBuffer.capacity())
        }
        byteBuffer[imageData]

        val iFact = if (mActivity.getOverlayView().width <= mActivity.getOverlayView().height) {
            image.width / mActivity.getOverlayView().width.toDouble()
        } else {
            image.height / mActivity.getOverlayView().height.toDouble()
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "")

        Log.i(TAG, "image.height" + image.height)
        Log.i(TAG, "image.width" + image.width)

        Log.i(TAG, "overlay.height" + mActivity.getOverlayView().height)
        Log.i(TAG, "overlay.width" + mActivity.getOverlayView().width)

        val size = mActivity.getOverlayView().size * iFact


        Log.i(TAG, "Obtained size 1: " + mActivity.getOverlayView().size)

        Log.i(TAG, "iFact: $iFact")
        Log.i(TAG, "calculated size: $size")

        val left = (image.width - size) / 2
        val top = (image.height - size) / 2

        Log.i(TAG, "left: $left")
        Log.i(TAG, "top: $top")

        val source = PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
            imageData,
            image.width, image.height,
            left.toInt(), top.toInt(),
            size.toInt(), size.toInt(),
            false
        )

        Log.i(TAG, "source.thumbnailHeight" +  source.thumbnailHeight.toString())
        Log.i(TAG, "source.thumbnailWidth" + source.thumbnailWidth.toString())

        mActivity.runOnUiThread {
            mActivity.showIntArray(source.renderThumbnail(), source.thumbnailHeight)
        }

        val binaryBitmap = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
        try {
            val result = reader.decodeWithState(binaryBitmap)
            listener.invoke(result.text)
        } catch (e: ReaderException) {
        } finally {
            reader.reset()
        }

        // Compute the FPS of the entire pipeline
        val frameCount = 10
        if (++frameCounter % frameCount == 0) {
            frameCounter = 0
            val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val delta = now - lastFpsTimestamp
            val fps = 1000 * frameCount.toFloat() / delta
            Log.d(TAG, "Analysis FPS: ${"%.02f".format(fps)}")
            lastFpsTimestamp = now
        }

        image.close()
    }
```

**Code to start camera:**

```
                val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

                val preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.setSurfaceProvider(contentFrame.surfaceProvider)
                    }

                overlayView = findViewById(R.id.overlay)

                val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setTargetResolution(Size(960, 960))
                    .build()

                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                    executor,
                    QRCodeImageAnalyzer (this) { response ->
                        if (response != null) {
                            handleResult(response)
                        }
                    }
                )

                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis)
```

Also, I get the image from **PlanarYUVLuminanceSource** after the cropping is done.

Can someone please help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some device have rotation special. you can use imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees() to get correct rotation of image. references with (ImageInfo) https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageInfo#getRotationDegrees()

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30137810)